# C++ substring why does it do that?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am trying to reverse order of a string 5 characters from end of string to beginning For example, if the input was "11111000002222233333", I want output to be "33333222220000011111"

```
string reverse(string str)
    {
        string tmp = "";
        for(int i = str.length(); i >= 5; i = i - 5)
        {
            tmp.append(str.substr(i - 5, i));
        }
        return tmp;
    };
```

lets just say that my input was "1000001010000000000010100" but it returns "101000000010100000000000010100010100000010000"

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using std::reverse?

Comment: Because I want every 5 characters to change order

Comment: Your example is very unclear as it seems to be a special case where whatever you're trying to accomplish and std::reverse give the same exact result.

Comment: yes it was very unclear example. so another example will be: i want to change "abcdefghij1234567890" to "6789012345fghijabcde" every 5 characters are stick together. So just think the 5 characters are one character

Comment: that's a lot clearer indeed. Feel free to edit your question itself next time when correcting things like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

> Returns a substring [pos, pos+count). If the requested substring
>   extends past the end of the string, or if count == npos, the returned
>   substring is [pos, size()).

```
std::string substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos) const;
```

Your mistake is that you treat `substr()` second parameter as position index.
But it's **substring length**, not end position.

Quick fix is `tmp.append(str.substr(i - 5, 5));`

Comment: Thanks you so much. I just thought it would be same as Java.